# Python : Adding a code routine at each line of a block of code

Tags: python, decorator, introspection

I want to have a piece of code run after each line of another block of code. For example, want to be able to evaluate a global variable before or after executing the next line of a function.

For example, below I try to print 'hello' before each line of the `foo()` function. I think that a decorator can help me but it would need some introspection feature in order to edit each line of my `foo()` function and add what I want before or after it.

I am trying to perform something like this :

```
>>> def foo():
...    print 'bar'
...    print 'barbar'
...    print 'barbarbar'

>>> foo()
hello
bar
hello
barbar 
hello
barbarbar
```

How can I perform this? would the `__code__` object help? do I need a decorator & introspection at the same time?

EDIT: Here is another example of the goal of this thread:

```
>>> def foo():
...    for i in range(0,3):
...        print 'bar'

>>> foo()
hello
bar
hello
bar 
hello
bar
```

In this new case, before printing each "bar", I want to print a "hello".

The main goal of this is to be able to execute another function or test any kind of global variable before executing the next line of the code. Imagine if a global variable is `True`, then the code goes to the next line; while if the global variable is `False`, then it stops the function execution.

EDIT:
In a way, i am looking for a tool to inject code inside another block of code.

EDIT:
Thank's to unutbu i have achieved this code :

```
import sys
import time
import threading

class SetTrace(object):
    """
    with SetTrace(monitor):
    """
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __enter__(self):
        sys.settrace(self.func)
        return self
    def __exit__(self, ext_type, exc_value, traceback):
        sys.settrace(None)
        # http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm
        # When __exit__ returns True, the exception is swallowed.
        # When __exit__ returns False, the exception is reraised.
        # This catches Sentinel, and lets other errors through
        # return isinstance(exc_value, Exception)

def monitor(frame, event, arg):
    if event == "line":
        if not running:
            raise Exception("global running is False, exiting")
    return monitor

def isRunning(function):
    def defaultBehavior(*args):
        with SetTrace(monitor):
            ret = function(*args)
            return ret
    return defaultBehavior

@isRunning
def foo():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print 'bar'

global running
running = True
thread = threading.Thread(target = foo)
thread.start()
time.sleep(3)
running = False
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [sys.settrace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace):

```
import sys
class SetTrace(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __enter__(self):
        sys.settrace(self.func)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, ext_type, exc_value, traceback):
        sys.settrace(None)

def monitor(frame, event, arg):
    if event == "line":
        print('hello')
        # print(frame.f_globals) 
        # print(frame.f_locals)  
    return monitor



def foo():
   print 'bar'
   print 'barbar'
   print 'barbarbar'

with SetTrace(monitor):
    foo()
```

yields

```
hello
bar
hello
barbar
hello
barbarbar
hello
```

Inside `monitor`, you can access the `foo`'s locals and globals using `frame.f_locals` and `frame.f_globals`.

See this [post](http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2005/04/20/tracing_python_code.html) for an example of how `sys.settrace` can be used for debugging.

---

**How to stop `foo` from within `monitor`:**

The most graceful way to do this would be to place a conditional statement inside `foo` so that `foo` checks when to exit. Then you can manipulate the value of the conditional from within `monitor` to control when `foo` exits.

However, if you do not want to or can not change `foo`, then an alternative is to raise an exception from within `monitor`. The exception will bubble up through the frame stack until it is caught. If you catch it in `SetTrace.__exit__`, then the flow of control will continue as though `foo` had just exited.

```
import sys
class Sentinel(Exception): pass

class SetTrace(object):
    """
    with SetTrace(monitor):
        ...
    """
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __enter__(self):
        sys.settrace(self.func)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, ext_type, exc_value, traceback):
        sys.settrace(None)
        # http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm
        # When __exit__ returns True, the exception is swallowed.
        # When __exit__ returns False, the exception is reraised.

        # This catches Sentinel, and lets other errors through
        return isinstance(exc_value, Sentinel)

def monitor(frame, event, arg):
    if event == "line":
        l = frame.f_locals
        x = l.get('x', 0)
        print('x = {}'.format(x))
        if x > 3:
            raise Sentinel()
    return monitor

def foo():
    x = 0
    while True:
        print 'bar'
        x += 1

with SetTrace(monitor):
    foo()
```

Comment: Thank's a lot, this seems to be close to this you are right, the main point of thread is not to debug, but more to be able to stop a block of code that is executing by changing the value of another global variable that this function will evaluate before executing each line of the code.

This would add a preemption point inside each line of the code, if a global toggle is false => then the function stop withtout going to the end, if the toggle is true => then the function execute the line and go to next one

Do i make this clear enough?

Comment: Yes, you can inspect *and change* the value of locals and globals from within `monitor`.

Comment: Thank's, but can I stop the current execution of the monitored function? in that case, stopping foo() from being executed? (in a way can I add return line when i want in between in order to finish my function?)

Comment: I'ved edited the post above to show how `foo` can be terminated from within `monitor`.

Comment: thank's a lot, it does work, i will add personnal modification in my post

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a debugger, take a look at the builtin [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pdb.html). With pdb you can do this:

```
>>> def foo():
...     import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
...     print 'bar'
...     print 'barbar'
...     print 'barbarbar'
... 
>>> 
>>> foo()
> <stdin>(3)foo()
(Pdb) print 'hi'
hi
(Pdb) n
bar
> <stdin>(4)foo()
(Pdb) n
barbar
> <stdin>(5)foo()
(Pdb) n
barbarbar
--Return--
> <stdin>(5)foo()->None
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> <stdin>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) n
>>>
```

Like most other debuggers, this allows you step through your code line by line. You can check out the documentation for further information, but in the above example the [`pdb.set_trace()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pdb.html#pdb.set_trace) -call sets up the debug entry point and brings up the pdb console. From the console you can modify variables and do all sorts of things. The `n` is simply a shorthand for `next` which steps one step forward.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer probably depends on what you actually want to do, but in order to do what you asked, I'd do this:

```
from itertools import chain

def print_(s):
    print s

def print_f(s):
   return (lambda: print_(s))

def execute_several(functions):
    for f in functions:
        f()

def prepend_printhello(function):
    return (print_f("hello"), function)

def foo():
    execute_several(chain(*map(prepend_printhello, map(print_f, ("bar", "barbar", "barbarbar")))))
```

Comment: This does not correspond to what i'm searching as it does change the way foo() function is coded creating 3 lamba function, i'm searching a way to keep a classic way of coding and add a decorator that will perform all this work.

Comment: BTW : there are behavior that can't be handle easily, imagine a foo() function with a for loop, i would like to perform my print 'hello' at each cycle of this loop, in a way, i'm searching for preemption point at each line of a code